# awk print variable with spaces

Tags: bash, awk

How do I pass a variable containing a space to awk as one variable?

code:

```
a="one"
b="two three"
c="four"
echo $a $b $c | awk '{ print "A="$1 "\nB="$2 "\nC="$3 }'
```

expected output:

```
A=one
B=two three
C=four
```

actual output:

```
A=one
B=two
C=three
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `awk`'s `-v` option to pass shell parameters to `awk` :

```
a="one"
b="two three"
c="four"

echo | awk -va="$a" -vb="$b" -vc="$c" '{ print "A="a "\nB="b "\nC="c }'
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the separator is `space`, there cannot be field values containing space.

Protecting with quotes won't help either since `awk` doesn't consider them as protecting the columns like a csv parser could do (unless you use the FPAT trick as Ed suggested).

```
$ echo "$a" \"$b\" "$c" | awk '{ print "A="$1 "\nB="$2 "\nC="$3 }'
A=one
B="two
C=three"
```

workaround: change field separator:

```
$ echo "$a,$b,$c" | awk -F, '{ print "A="$1 "\nB="$2 "\nC="$3 }'
A=one
B=two three
C=four
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a million possible answers and which one is right for you depends on what you are trying to do which you haven't told us. Here's another possibility using GNU awk for FPAT:

```
$ echo "\"$a\" \"$b\" \"$c\"" | awk -v FPAT='"[^"]+"' '{print "A="$1 "\nB="$2 "\nC="$3 }'
A="one"
B="two three"
C="four"
```

Comment: interesting, not from command line of course. But if you have a file protected with quotes, yes, that's a nice feature. Consider that most csv files have quotes _only_ when needed. Is it possible to do both cases? Also: there may be quotes in the fields themselves in quoted csv files... Tricky cases.

Comment: Not sure what "not from command line of course" means. Yes, a typical setting of FPAT for CSV files where some fields are quoted and some aren't would be `FPAT='([^,]*)|("[^"]+")'` and if you want to handle escaped quotes then you can use `FPAT='([^,]*)|("([^"]|"")*")'`, assuming escaping quotes within fields is done by doubling up the quotes, otherwise replace `""` with `\\"` or whatever you use to escape your quotes.

Comment: from command line: I mean you make a lot of efforts to add quotes where a comma would be easier. But it seems that your method covers all cases. Me I prefer python.

Comment: A comma would only be easier if the text didn't contain a comma but in any case, there's no effort, it just is whatever the input is and the OP hasn't told us enough to know what he actually needs. wrt prefering python - yeah, everyone has their preferences. I haven't found a use for python myself and several platforms I work on just don't have it and can't install it but I've only been programming for 35 years so I'm sure the need for it is just around the corner :-).

Comment: I let all bash/awk/sed technologies go when I had too many problems with MSYS on Windows. Python solved them all. I've only been programming for 24 years when I found out. So all hope is not lost for you :)